# How to get the passed options to a Symfony form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to extend a Symfony 2.8 Form Type, following this http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/form/create_form_type_extension.html

In my `ObjectType` form I have something like this, where I create my form. My form includes a field of Type `MyExtendedType`

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $passed_options = array('aKey'=>'aValue', ...);

    $builder
        ->add('someotherfield', 'SomeOtherStandardType', ..)
        ->add('fieldname', 'AppBundle\Form\Type\MyExtendedType', $passed_options)
        ->add('someotherfield', 'SomeOtherStandardType', ..)
        //...
    ;
}
```

In my `MyExtendedType` I have this in which I want to substitute `fieldname` in `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA`

```
public function getParent()
{
    return 'Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType';
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($builder, $options) {
        $form = $event->getForm()->getParent();
        $modified_options = $options; //this is not correct because there are all the resolved options of the field
        $modified_options['aKey'] = 'anotherValue';
        $form->add($builder->getName(), 'Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType', $modified_options);
    });
}
```

The problem is that in `MyExtendedType` I need to access only the `$passed_options`. In `$options` I have all the resolved options that are initialized from the Form component, and doing as the previous code the field is not properly built, because of the presence of options in contrast with each other (e.g. query_builder, choices, choice_list..).

Here is the question:
how can I access just the `$passed_options` using the Form component? I don't want to set the properties in the `ObjectType` in order to have a generic approach.

Comment: Have you tried turning your type into a service and configure the service once ?

Comment: Can you explain why you need to distinguish passed options from how the options are eventually resolved by the Form component?

Comment: @xabbuh I have an  EntityType that loads data from a very long table, thus rendering the field in the view is very expensive. I would like to use Select2 to manage that select field (providing data via Ajax), so I was trying to list on FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA to replace the field setting `choices` to just those already selected and on PRE_SUBMIT to set choices via `query_builder` (forrvalidation). If the user wants to modify the field, the data are provided by Select2 via Ajax. If i use all the `$options` it does not work because of a sort of priority in evaluating them in the Form component.

Comment: I don't seems another way to achieve it other than replicate `ResolvedTypeDataCollectorProxy` behavior (for no debug mode only).