# How to set default form required state (and override in builder) in Symfony 3?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to build a form and have the default 'required' state set to false,
and then have the form build configuration override that, setting some to true.

If I add no configurationOptions, the fields default to 'required' as true, and I can override them with specific configurations.

However, if I add:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefault('required', false);
}
```

I can't override that in the specific config (this does not make required true):

```
->add('name',TextType::class, array(
    'required' => true,
    'constraints' => array(new Length(array('min' => 3)))
))
```

Is there a way to do this, or must I always set no default and specify each config?

Comment: Not sure I understood your question: do you want to change the default setting of the `required` option to `false` globally for all forms of your app, and then set it on `true` only in the fields you want?

Comment: Not necessarily for all forms of my app, but for one form in particular.  That way if I have a very long form with very few required fields, I'd like to set the default required to false, and then set only the few necessary to true.  I assumed that is how the setDefault configure option would have worked, but it doesn't appear to be working that way.

Comment: I would create a form extension. Tomorrow I'll write my answer

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with the [**PRE_SET_DATA** Symfony form event](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#adding-an-event-listener-to-a-form-class).  Essentially what you have to do is re-add all of your form fields in that form event.  When you add them in the form event, they will overwrite your existing form fields of the same name.  You want to add the field back with all of the information the same, while replacing the form options array and manually setting the **required** option to **false**.  Have a look:

```
class MyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(/* ... */)
            ->add(/* ... */)
        ;

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();

            // loop through each form field
            foreach ($form->all() as $field) {
                $config  = $field->getConfig();
                $options = $config->getOptions();

                // re-add the form field and overwrite the 'required' option
                // this overwrites the existing field
                $form->add(
                    $field->getName(),
                    get_class($config->getType()->getInnerType()),
                    array_replace($options, ['required' => false])
                );
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Note that the following line:

```
get_class($config->getType()->getInnerType()),
```

should instead be

```
$config->getType()->getName()
```

if you are using a Symfony version earlier than Symfony 3.

As some background, by design the **FormConfigInterface** interface does not allow modification after the config has already been set.  If you take a peek inside there, it only has `get` and `has` functions - so nothing can be manually set.  It has to be done when adding the form/form field.

If you wanted this global across your project you could make a base form type that includes this functionality in the `buildForm()` event, and then all of your child forms could call the parent after they set themselves.  You could also do this for individual fields - instead of looping with

```
foreach ($form->all() as $field) {
```

you could simply change a particular field with

```
$config = $form->get('field_name');
$options = $config->getOptions();

$form->add(
    'field_name',
    get_class($config->getType()->getInnerType()),
    array_replace($options, ['required' => false])
);
```

Comment: I think `array_replace($options, ['required' => false])` could lead to issues because $options has been already processed by the form component, they are not just the short $options provided in the FormType, thus adding a new field with all that $options may create a field different from what the user expects, or not create a field at all and give an error. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42900331/how-to-get-the-passed-options-to-a-symfony-form

Comment: I'd have to test that out.  My `$options` are directly from the configuration of that individual field/form.  I see the question you linked to, but that approach directly passed the FormType `$options` to the closure, rather than using the `getOptions()` method like I am using. I did test out my solution directly and it worked for a basic case, but I'll play around with it today to see if there is the issue you described.

Comment: did you try it?

Comment: Not yet - been caught up with a lot of other things.  I'll try to get around to it at some point.

Answer (score 0):

This form extension (see http://symfony.com/doc/master/form/create_form_type_extension.html) let you default **all** your fields of **all** forms with `required=false`

```
// src/AppBundle/Form/Extension/RequiredDefaultsToFalseExtension.php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class RequiredDefaultsToFalseExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{

    /**
     * Returns the name of the type being extended.
     *
     * @return string The name of the type being extended
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return FormType::class;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {

        $resolver->setDefault('required', false);
    }

}
```

you have to register your extension

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.required_defaults_to_false_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Extension\RequiredDefaultsToFalseExtension
        tags:
            - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType }
```

and you are done, you have to do nothing more.

Having in mind that the `required` option acts only in the view of the form (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#required) but has some reflects with `empty_data` option (http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/form.html#empty-data) you could also use this extension **instead of** the previous one (maybe you have to adjust it to fit exactly your needs)

```
// src/AppBundle/Form/Extension/RootFormRequiredDefaultsToFalseExtension.php
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class RootFormRequiredDefaultsToFalseExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{

    /**
     * Returns the name of the type being extended.
     *
     * @return string The name of the type being extended
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return FormType::class;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {

        $resolver->setDefault('root_form_required_defaults_to_false', false);
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        if ($form->getParent()) {
            if ($form->getParent()->getConfig()->getOption('root_form_required_defaults_to_false')) {
                $view->vars['required']=false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you have to register your extension

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.root_form_required_defaults_to_false_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Extension\RootFormRequiredDefaultsToFalseExtension
        tags:
            - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType }
```

and in the form type where you want to use this, you have to enable it with

```
// src/AppBundle/Form/MyFormType.php
// ..
/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        // ..
        'root_form_required_defaults_to_false'=>true
    ));
}
```

In the end, remember that you can disable html5 validation on a per-form basis with this attribute set in your root form options or in you twig view. (http://symfony.com/doc/master/forms.html#form-validation)

```
// src/AppBundle/Form/MyFormType.php
// ..
/**
 * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
 */
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        // ..
    'attr' => ['novalidate'=>'novalidate'],
));
```

Comment: Your first piece of code says `'required => true` - did you mean to put `required => false`?